# execute script correctly when pop up opens and closes

Tags: javascript

I have an issue executing these scripts correctly.

I have the following two scripts that need to execute at different stages of customer interaction.
execute script:

1. When the Quick View's popin is opened by the user.
2. When the Quick View's popin is closed by the user.

```js
//When the Quick View's popin is closed by the user.
window._uxa = window._uxa || [];
window._uxa.push([
  "trackPageview",
  window.location.pathname +
    window.location.hash.replace("#", "?__") +
    "?cs-popin-quickView",
]);

//When the Quick View's popin is opened by the user.
window._uxa = window._uxa || [];
window._uxa.push([
  "trackPageview",
  window.location.pathname + window.location.hash.replace("#", "?__"),
]);
```

Im having issue set up tracking for a popup. Im expecting to track pageviews when popup open and closes.

Comment: can you please tell what it is you are expecting and what is the issue you are having?

Comment: explained above